# How to link the pdf files in assets?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to show the PDF files without using the network connection, So I thought to put that PDF files into an asset but the **"react-native link"** comment does not link the PDF files it's only linking the font file,I'm also tried with **react-native-asset** package but that is also gives the same result. Could you please give some idea about linking the  PDF files into an asset.
Thanks a lot!

"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/",
      "./assets/pdf/"
    ]
  }

Comment: have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf

Comment: Hi Chris Chen and Abanou Istfanous ,
yes I'm using react-native-pdf it's perfectly working in emulator. But after creating the signed apk the pdf file does not showing.

Comment: Here is the link which answer of my question
[In this link we can add the PDF file into asset file by adding the PDF file directly into android/app/src/main/assets/PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805955/react-native-pdf-showing-on-android-simulator-but-getting-error-on-actual-andro)

Comment: Here is the link which answer of my question file[In this link we can add the PDF file into asset file by adding the PDF file directly into android/app/src/main/assets/PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805955/react-native-pdf-showing-on-android-simulator-but-getting-error-on-actual-andro)